# Trouble Using the new rematchWithCompletionHandler method from Game Center

Tags: ios, game-center

I am making a turnbased game using the gamecenter api. I wanted to make a one press button to rematch players so they don't have to go through the gamecenter view controllers and re invite the same player. In this question [iOS Game Kit Turn Based Match Programatic Rematch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148430/ios-game-kit-turn-based-match-programatic-rematch) the asker notes later on that ios 6.0 makes this really easy using rematchWithCompletionHandler. I have tried to use this in my game and have only gotten unkown selector errors or NSErrors saying that the match I am trying to create is not possible.

```
[currentMatch rematchWithCompletionHandler:^(GKTurnBasedMatch *match, NSError *error)
         {
             if (error) {
                 NSLog(@"%@", error);
             }

             else
             {
                 currentMatch = match;
                 currentMatch.message = @"Rematch";
             }

         }];
```

Is there some stage that the match has to be in before calling rematch? or something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

rematchWithCompletionHandler appears to only work when a match has been correctly ended by all players involved with the match.

Comment: With 'correctly ended' do you mean that each peer has to have called GkMatch disconnect() ?

Comment: @Bram, this question was talking about GKTurnBasedMatch. GKTurnBasedMatch does not have a disconnect method. Here are some ways to end a turn based match: participantQuitInTurnWithOutcome:nextParticipants:turnTimeout:matchData:completionHandler, 
participantQuitOutOfTurnWithOutcome:withCompletionHandler, 
endMatchInTurnWithMatchData:completionHandler

Comment: I have a real time match, and when I request a rematch, I get a callback without error, but expectedPlayers is 1, not 0.

Comment: Sorry, I don't currently know about real time matches. Maybe you could make a new question about it? I think you would have a better chance of getting an answer.

Comment: @Bram I know it's been over ten years haha, but were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

It only works for me when the two players are Game Center friends.