# Why is match.rematch returning 0 players in Game Center peer-to-peer game?

Tags: ios, gamekit

There's a [[similar question from '12][1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052638/trouble-using-the-new-rematchwithcompletionhandler-method-from-game-center)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052638/trouble-using-the-new-rematchwithcompletionhandler-method-from-game-center), but it's turn-by-turn game (may or may not make difference), it was not resolved, and there've possibly been Game Center/GameKit changes since them.

Simple case is two players on iOS, and both tap a button that executes this code (`currentMatch` is a class property `GKMatch?`):

```
    if let match = currentMatch {
        print("create rematch completion handler")
        match.rematch(completionHandler: {(newMatch, error) in
            print("execute rematch completion handler")
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
            if let newMatch = newMatch {
                print("rematch completed \(newMatch.players.count)")
                self.currentMatch = newMatch
            }
        })
    }
```

The log returns:

```
create rematch completion handler
match did change state ‎“‪Player2” 2
disconnected from ‎“‪Player2”
execute rematch completion handler
rematch completed 0
```

Thus, GameKit is disconnecting the players on its own, executing the completion handler, and seemingly creating a new match with 0 players.

Any suggestions on what to do differently to have the rematch with the original players? Has anyone ever had this work? Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I used to have this working, but I was trying to update my code and I appear to have broken the rematch functionality somehow and nothing I try is working at all.